# Sink faucet cartridge pops out with geyser-like leak

Tags: bathroom, repair, plumbing-fixture

I've never heard of this but today my wife screamed that her bathroom faucet (cold side) EXPLODED. Sure enough, the cartridge together with the knob and all just popped up and out resulting in a geyser of water. The faucet was in the off position and she hadn't touched the knob...it just suddenly blew.

We actually have low water pressure in the house - so low I had to install a low pressure shower head in that bathroom. The fixtures are original to the house built in 1992, although I've replaced one leaking cartridge (dripping faucet) in this bathroom about a year ago and another dripping faucet cartridge in a separate bathroom a couple of months ago.

I can see no damage to the cartridge that popped out. assume I'll just need to replace the cartridge(s) in that sink, but will that by itself prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Threads on the nut and/or stem holding the cartridge on are probably striped.  Probably looking at replacement.

Comment: did you forget to install a retaining clip when you replaced the cartridge?

Comment: Or did the retaining clip corrode or break?